# How to check a webpage for updates

Tags: browsing

Sometimes there are news pages on interesting sites that doesn't have any feed service. Is there some way (webapp, browser plugin, or something) to keep those page checked for updates?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you receive the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [New Google Reader Feature Can Create a Feed for Any Site](http://www.webpronews.com/topnews/2010/01/26/new-google-reader-feature-can-create-a-feed-for-any-site)

Comment: +1 - I've tried it.  It's not as "pretty" as a real feed (no headings and such for updates) but it works!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this Firefox extension will help you?

[Check4Change](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3028/)

> Check4Change (aka C4C) is a simple
>   extension that allows you to
>   periodically check a web-page for
>   updates...